# How to change encoding in PhpStorm?

Tags: encoding, phpstorm

I have to change file encoding in every project to `utf-8`. It always shows `windows-1251` . So how can I change file encoding forever. I tried change in settings `IDE Encoding` and `Project Encoding` to `utf-8` but it is  not working.

Answer (score 1):

Both encoding settings (IDE-level and project-level) apply for new files created by PhpStorm.

Afaik, PhpStorm does not provide any way to bulk change the encoding of many files at once. You have to open each file, change its encoding from the drop-down menu in the status bar (or `menu` -> `File` -> `File Encoding`) then save it.

To make the things easier you can add a key combination for the `File Encoding` command (in the `Key Bindings` section of the `Preferences`) or record a macro (but it won't save you more key presses).

Comment: *"Afaik, PhpStorm does not provide any way to bulk change the encoding of many files at once."* It does. Select desired files/folders in Project View and then invoke `File | File Encoding`. Have not used this myself though (had no need to do that with encoding) ... but it does work like that for changing Line Ending .. so _should work_ here as well.

Comment: Indeed, it works. The drawback is that the command is available in the menu when only files are selected in the Project View. It doesn't work for folders.

Comment: "_You have to open each file, change its encoding from the drop-down menu in the status bar_ " as I said I have to change every file